# How do you persist image references across app updates on iOS devices

Tags: ios, flutter, persistent-storage, flutter-ios

I have developed a Flutter app that captures images using the camera and I store references to the image files using `Shared Preferences`.

When I upgrade the iOS app, the `Shared Preference` filename persists as expected, but the image no longer displays on the iOS device (and no longer seems to exist) `File(_imageFileRef).existsSync()` is false

For example, on iPhone, the image file is saved as

`/private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/580A9879-23CD-413D-A785-DB910673DF74/tmp/some_guid_image_name.jpg`

When the app is upgraded, this file no longer seems to exist.

Where should I be saving the image files to in iOS so that they persist across upgrades?

The functionality works perfectly on Android devices.

Answer (score 1):

Having received no answers, I delved a bit deeper and discovered that...

...the `tmp` directory in which the images are being written is for temporary files that do not need to persist between launches of your app. Your app should remove files from this directory when they are no longer needed; however, the system may purge this directory when your app is not running. The contents of this directory are not backed up by iTunes or iCloud.

So in order for the data to persist over app updates, I need to be writing to the `Documents` directory

[Info obtained from here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html)